# Как сделать переключатель количества элементов на странице?

Tags: yii2, yii

Нужно - Вывод товаров по: 10 20 30
Как можно реализовать такой функционал на yii?

Вывод элементов

```
           <? foreach($products as $product) : ?>
                <? $this->renderPartial('_item', array(
                    'product' => $product,
                    'section' => $section,
                    'price' => $price,
                )); ?>
            <? endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать посредством yii\data\Pagination.

Controller action:

```html
function actionIndex()
{
    $query = Article::find()->where(['status' => 1]);
    $countQuery = clone $query;
    $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count()]);
    $products = $query->offset($pages->offset)
        ->limit($pages->limit)
        ->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
         'products' => $products,
         'pages' => $pages,
    ]);
}
```

View:

```html
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $this->renderPartial('_item', array(
                'product' => $product,
                'section' => $section,
                'price' => $price,
            ));
}

// display pagination
echo LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pages,
]);
```

Подробнее: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html